# Facebook Application in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, facebook-sdk-4.0

here is my problem: I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 website with security managed with Identity (Owin).
Then I have added a Facebook Application as a new Area within the website, by following the official Facebook Application Template: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

As you can see, the Facebook App Template relies on the Facebook SDK to manage authentication, this creates problems since the user will not be authenticated by Identity and thus all the logics won't work such as:
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)

Is there any method in the Identity framework to manually create and validate the auth?

Comment: Why did you decide not to use Identity's Facebook authentication?

Comment: I use it in the normal website, but for the facebook app I used the FB SDK as in the tutorial, that's my problem, I have two systems to accomplish the same task